# Can't connect to Gmail on outlook app: We encountered a problem while verifying your identity

Tags: outlook

Today my Gmail accounts on two different laptops both failed to be connected by the local outlook apps on Mac.

Outlook popped up a Gmail log-in window but after logging in I was always presented with this message:

[image]

```
We encountered a problem while verifying your identity.
Contact Support
Less Details
Status: 500
Error Code: InternalServerError
Error Message: Internal server error
```

So, what is the cause and how can I fix it? It seems to be that I'm blocked by Gmail or Gmail has some problems on their side.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its not about web applications. It's about desktop applications accessing a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same exact issue this morning.   Was fine last night.  Logging directly into Gmail versus Outlook seems to be ok so its def between Outlook and Gmail.  Hope someone finds the answer !

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue across multiple domains - all mac client versions of outlook talking to Gmail account - pc version ok.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Having the exact same issue on outlook on all my devices. Have attempted resyncing, resetting the account, logging back in and it does seem like an issue between Outlook and Gmail.

Some devices' outlook have no emails at all like the account is empty with no folders or items, and some are just not syncing from late last night/this morning. Weirdly tried viewing it on legacy outlook and only emails up to Nov 2021 came through.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that it is indeed Google's issue and it has been fixed now!